# Error Calling FCM Push Notification api throu

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting the below error in my Java Application while sending Push Notification using Firebase which is deployed on Tomcat CentOS server.

But the same code is working fine and sending Push Notification from my local PC environment.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Error while
calling FCM backend service
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:500)
~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:479)
~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:76)
~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        at com.mymediport.mmpnotification.service.FCMService.sendAndGetResponse(FCMService.java:40)
~[classes/:0.0.1]
        at com.mymediport.mmpnotification.service.FCMService.sendMessageToToken(FCMService.java:35)
~[classes/:0.0.1]
        at com.mymediport.mmpnotification.model.PushNotificationModel.SendPushToAccount(PushNotificationModel.java:44)
~[classes/:0.0.1]
        at com.mymediport.mmpnotification.model.PushNotificationModel$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ac386b15.invoke(<generated>)
[classes/:0.0.1]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.lambda$doSubmit$3(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:276)
~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181] Caused by: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException:
Error while calling FCM backend service
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.send(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:129)
~[firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$1.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:139)
~[firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$1.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:136)
~[firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36)
~[firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:111)
~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:58)
~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:75)
~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        ... 3 common frames omitted Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account:
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:395)
~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.11.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:179)
~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.11.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:165)
~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.11.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:96)
~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.11.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.firebase.internal.FirebaseRequestInitializer.initialize(FirebaseRequestInitializer.java:55)
~[firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:93)
~[google-http-client-1.25.0.jar:1.25.0]
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildPostRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:133)
~[google-http-client-1.25.0.jar:1.25.0]
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.sendSingleRequest(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:147)
~[firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.send(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:125)
~[firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar:na]
        ... 9 common frames omitted Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
~[google-http-client-1.25.0.jar:1.25.0]
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
~[google-http-client-1.25.0.jar:1.25.0]
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:393)
~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.11.0.jar:na]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Here is the code which I am using:

```
    public void sendMessageToToken(PushNotificationRequest request)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Message message = getPreconfiguredMessageToToken(request);
        String response = sendAndGetResponse(message);
        logger.info("Sent message to token. Device token: " + request.getToken() + ", " + response);
    }

    private String sendAndGetResponse(Message message) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message).get();
    }
    private ApnsConfig getApnsConfig(String topic) {
        return ApnsConfig.builder()
                .setAps(Aps.builder().setCategory(topic).setThreadId(topic).build()).build();
    }

    private Message getPreconfiguredMessageToToken(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        return getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder(request).setToken(request.getToken())
                .build();
    }
    private Message.Builder getPreconfiguredMessageBuilder(PushNotificationRequest request) {
        AndroidConfig androidConfig = getAndroidConfig(request.getTopic());
        ApnsConfig apnsConfig = getApnsConfig(request.getTopic());
        return Message.builder()
                .setApnsConfig(apnsConfig).setAndroidConfig(androidConfig).setNotification(
                        new Notification(request.getTitle(), request.getMessage()));
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: So this is your actual error `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`, check your server has a stable, decent network connection.

Comment: Yes it is stale I checked it multiple times.